# Can every complex space be covered by a finite number of Stein spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Can every complex space be covered by a finite number of Stein spaces?

Comment: I edited the question to provide context; feel free to rollback any edits others (including me) make to your questions.

Comment: I deleted your proposed definition of a Stein space, as it was clearly incorrect - what you defined were only Stein manifolds, not  Stein spaces. Even if you replaced "submanifold" with "subspace", it would still be incorrect, as the embedding theorem for Stein manifolds fails for general Stein spaces. I can write out a definition of a Stein space, if you think it is necessary, but I believe that people who know what complex spaces are probably also know Stein spaces.

Comment: I know that relatively compact stricty pseudoconvex surfaces can be covered by two open Stein (and it's not easy to prove). It's probably wrong in general, but I'll have to find a counterexample ^^

Comment: A counterexample should be non compact of course.